# golang how to connect multi cluster neo4j db?

Tags: go, neo4j, cypher

```golang
dbUri := "neo4j://localhost:7687"
driver, err := neo4j.NewDriver(dbUri, neo4j.BasicAuth("username", "password", ""))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver driver source

In given golang driver example, It uses single cluster.
If we have multi cluster neo4j, can we give comma seperated cluster ips or not?

I mean;

```
dbUri := "neo4j://11.222.33:7687,neo4j://44.66.789:7687"
driver, err := neo4j.NewDriver(dbUri, neo4j.BasicAuth("username", "password", ""))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you only need to give ip address of one cluster member, rest it will pick up

Answer (score 0):

It cannot connect directly to multiple clusters from the client.

But you can use neo4j fabric to integrate multiple clusters so that you can write queries that use multiple databases of that fabric setup in a single query.

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/fabric/